# single frame loop, gotoandplay same frame

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm having trouble with something that should be incredibly basic, yet i have no idea how to solve my problem.

---

**frame1:**

x = 1

button1 makes x = 3

**frame2:**

trace x

gotoAndPlay(2)

---

**the problem:**

trace always = 1, even after you hit the button.

it shows x as being 3 when you hit the button but it reverts back right away, so it looks like gotoAndPlay(2) is still playing frame 1.

**how do i stop it from reseting my variables?**

Comment: if the variable name is really `x` you should check the actual coordinate in frame 2

Comment: if you don't trace anything on frame 1 and then it is tracing x = 1 that means it is playing frame 2 but your button code is wrong. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to remain on frame 2 use gotoAndStop(2);

If you're wanting to create a loop for frame 2 try adding gotoAndPlay(2); to frame 3.

So frame 1 code:

```
var x:int = 1;
```

Button code would be moving to frame 2.
Code on frame 2 would be

```
x = 3;
trace(x);
```

Comment: gotoAndStop() on frame2 means the function called on frame2 isnt called, which is a problem.

However setting gotoAndPlay(2) on frame3 worked like a charm, cheers.

Comment: @Brae this shouldn't be the case, gotoAndStop still allows frame script to run.

Comment: @George You would think that wouldn't you, but it seems not to be the case. (I hate flash.)

Comment: @Brae It definitely does run frame scripts, can you post your code and where it is located? It could be an ordering thing.

Comment: @George it does it with any code, just put a trace on frame2 then under it put gotoAndStop(2) and it will only play once, yet if you don't put the gotoAndStop(2) and put a gotoAndPlay(2) on frame3 it works. Doesn't matter now, I was only trying to solve the problem for this instance, I hate flash and don't really care what the 'correct' answer is. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @Brae That's because you tell it to `gotoAndStop(2)` on frame 2 which is telling it to `stop()`. It works on frame 3 because it is actually on different frame from the gotoAndStop. I will pester no more.